# Java Google guava multimap: Get all the list entrys

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I am using a multimap like this

```
Multimap<String, MyObject> tasksMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

Where there can be multiple items for the same key, get the List value for every key in the map?

Answer (score 1):

[`.asMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap--) lets you get a map and you can then iterate over its `.entrySet()`.

Something like

```
for (Entry<String, Collection<MyObject>> e : tasksMap.asMap().entrySet()) {
  String key = e.getKey();
  Collection<MyObject> values = e.getValue();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [get](https://guava.dev/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#get-K-) method to get all values for a key

```
List<MyObject> values = tasksMap.get(key);
```

or use [values](https://guava.dev/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#values--) to get all values for every key in map

```
 Collection<List<MyObject>> values = tasksMap.values();
```

or [entries](https://guava.dev/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#entries--) to get all entries

```
Collection<Map.Entry<String, List<MyObject>>> entries =  tasksMap.entries()
```